# Question on Calculus of Variation: Euler-Lagrange equation without integral constraint

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

> Let $\;y:U \to \mathbb R^m\;$ where $\;U\subset \mathbb R^n\;$ and
>   $\;n,m \gt 1\;$. Find the Euler-Lagrange equation of the following
>   functional :
>
> $\;J(y)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{U} {\vert Dy \vert}^2\;dx\;$
>
> subject to the pointwise constraint: $\;{\vert y \vert}^2 = 1\;$
>
> that is, that $\;y\;$ take values in the unit sphere $\;S^{m-1}\;$.

To begin with, I have to mention I have the solution of the above exercise. "The corresponding Euler-Lagrange system of PDE is

**$\;\Delta y ={\vert Dy \vert}^2 y\;$** where the term $\;{\vert Dy \vert}^2\;$ is the Lagrange multiplier for the constraint".

The problem is I 'm having trouble getting my head around it. Since today I've only seen this kind of problems:

[image]

for which the Euler-Lagrange equation is given by:

[image]

**1. How should I handle the above problem since the constraint is not an integral one?
 2. How could I find $\;λ\;$ by the given conditions?**

I've been stuck to this so I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $x\in U\subset\mathbb{R}$? so $dx$ is a short for $dx_1\dots dx_n$, right? and what is $|Dy|$  exactly? I think it is the modulus of the determinant of the Jacobian matrix, right? So its entries would be $Dy_{ij}=\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial x_j}$

Comment: @minimax Well yes and $\;\vert Dy \vert\;$ is the Frobenius norm of the gradient matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>If you want to work with what you know, you can convert the pointwise constraint to an integral one by constructing a positive "error function" to match: note that $|y|^2 = 1$ everywhere if and only if $\int (|y|^2 - 1)^2=0$.</s>

It's not too hard to do this from first principles - if $y$ is a critical point of $J$ constrained to take values in the sphere, then for any perturbation $y(s)$ of $y$ (with the same constraint) we must have $$0=\frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0}\frac12\int |D(y(s))|^2=\int Dy(0) \cdot Dy_s(0)=-\int\Delta y\cdot y_s,$$ where $y_s$ denotes $\partial y / \partial s$. Since a vector field $V$ can be realized as a $y_s$ if and only if $V(x)$ is tangential to the sphere at the point $y(x)$, we thus have $\int \Delta y^\perp \cdot V = 0$ for all $V$, where $\Delta y^\perp = \Delta y - (\Delta y \cdot y) y$ is the tangential part of the Laplacian. Thus we must have $\Delta y^\perp = 0;$ i.e. $\Delta y$ is parallel to $y$.

We can write this using a Lagrange multiplier as $\Delta y = \lambda y$. Now, to find $\lambda$ we need to use the constraint. From the product rule you can obtain $$\frac 1 2\Delta |y|^2 =y \cdot\Delta y +|Dy|^2,$$which must be  zero (since $|y|^2$ is constant). Since $y$ satisfies $\Delta y = \lambda y$, we thus have $$0=\lambda |y|^2 + |Dy|^2=\lambda + |Dy|^2;$$ so we can solve for $\lambda,$ obtaining the constrained Euler-Lagrange equation $$\Delta y = -|Dy|^2 y.$$ (I am reasonably sure the sign error is in your source, not my calculations.)

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answer! You were right about the sign error, it was my mistake! Converting the constraint into an integral one was great idea also. However I've got one more problem. I ended up with this E-L eq $\;-\Delta y^j=4λy^j({\vert y \vert}^2-1)\;$ since $\;G_{y^j} =4y^j({\vert y \vert}^2-1)\;$, which is not in the suggested form. What did I miss?

Comment: @kaithkolesidou: this is in the suggested form - as I warned, my $\lambda$ differs from yours by a scalar multiple.

Comment: The reason I get confused is because in my way, $\;-\Delta y^j=4λy^j({\vert y \vert}^2-1)\;=0\;$ due to constraint. The appearance of $\;({\vert y \vert}^2-1)\;$ isn't a problem here?

Comment: @kaithkolesidou: oh, you're right - perhaps this method is not as legitimate as I thought. (I also think the the Lagrange multiplier for an integral constraint should be a global constant, not just a scalar.) The derivation from first principles that I give is certainly correct.

Comment: I was trying to find an alternative answer to my problem but I'm afraid yours is way better. However I'll bother you once more because I have some questions: 1) $\;\int Dy(0) \cdot Dy_s(0)=-\int\Delta y\cdot y_s\;$ after using 2nd Green's formula. But why is $\;\int_{\partial U} \frac{\partial y}{\partial η} y_s \;dS\;$ equal to zero? I used the constraint for $\;y\;$ but I concluded to this $\;y \cdot y_s=0\;$

Comment: 2)Is$ \;\int Dy(0) \cdot Dy_s(0)=-\int\Delta y(0)\cdot y_s(0)\;$ or not? 3)You write the Laplacian as a sum of its tangential and normal components and then take inner product with $\;V\;$ and this is why you end up to this $\;\int \Delta y^\perp \cdot V = 0\;$. Have I understood it right?

Comment: 1) On noncompact domains, the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation is usually done formally, neglecting boundary terms - the exact answer to your question will depend on your exact situation. To make this rigorous, typically one would work with some asymptotic condition, e.g. that $Dy \to 0$ sufficiently quick at infinity or that $y$ is constant outside some ball. 2) Yes. 3) Correct. My choice of notation is probably very confusing here, $y^\perp$ usually denotes the normal part, not tangential part.